# How do I add a .jar file to Rhino's classpath?

Tags: java, jar, classpath, rhino

I am scripting Java via Rhino, and I would like to use the JCodec library. I put the `jcodec-0.1.9.jar` file in the same directory, and I added it via `-cp` on the command-line.  The command to invoke Rhino looks like:

```
java -cp "rhino-1.7.7.1.jar;jcodec-0.1.9.jar;." org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main -opt 9 js/main.js %*
```

However, the library doesn't load at all, since all of its classes remain undefined. For example, running:

```
print(java.lang.Class.forName('org.jcodec.api.awt.SequenceEncoder'))
```

throws a `ClassNotFoundException`, while it doesn't for say, `'javax.swing.JFrame'`.

I feel like I'm not including it correctly, but everywhere I've looked, this seems to be the way. Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I don't think its possible, see https://developer.jboss.org/thread/201217?tstart=0

Comment: @piyushj According to the [Rhino documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino/Scripting_Java), it should be: "_External packages and classes can also be used as in Rhino. Make sure your .jar or .class file is on you classpath then you may import them into your JavaScript application._"

Answer (score 0):

try the following to make sure that the current directory is in your classpaht:

```
java -cp ".\rhino-1.7.7.1.jar;.\jcodec-0.1.9.jar;." org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell
```

Note: if you're on UNIX change the .\ to ./ and the ; to :

### UPDATED:

The class you are trying to reference does not have an 'awt' in it.  Should be:

```
  org.jcodec.api.SequenceEncoder
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I tried it, but it made no difference... :(